# Add field in Pull Request template for Git in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, markdown, pull-request

I am planning to add a new field in my pull request template in order to enforce a check list for the developers to complete before they submit the pull request for review.

For now, I have created a markdown file "PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md", and placed following contents there -

```
- [ ] Functionality unit tested
- [ ] Followed coding standard
- [ ] Followed database standard
- [ ] Local build successful
```

But this displays check boxes in the description field. I am looking to add a new field in the pull request template independent of description field.

Also, I would like to track the history of user's actions on these check boxes, but that's not priority, but yes, a new field for this check list is much required for me at this stage.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: I really hope that you will find a solution, but I sounds not easy to achieve this. One incredible hard way I could imagine is to use the [REST API of pullre quests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) and wrap a custom application around it. But I beleave you want to keep everything inside azure devops?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? I have the same problem. I need some checkboxes that requires check before pull request approves..

Comment: not really, unfortunately, this seems an only option. I raised a request in UserVoice platform, but it didnt get votes and so committee closed for obvious reasons. I have recreated request today and hoping to get some votes for committee to get notice - https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Request-to-add-a-new-field-for-checklist/1329068?entry=myfeedback&space=21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this displays check boxes in the description field. I am looking to add a new field in the pull request template independent of description field.

I am afraid we could not add a new field in the pull request template independent of description field.

According to the document [Improve pull request descriptions using templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-templates?view=azure-devops):

> **What is a pull request template?**
>
> A pull request template is a file containing **markdown text** that is added to your **pull request description** when the pull request is created.

We could to know that the template provided by MS only refers to **the markdown added to the pull request description**, it is not like workitem, which we could add custom fields through a custom process. MS does not provide a custom field other than the description, so we could not add new field in pull request template, have to add a new field in the description field.

BTW, if add a new field in the pull request template independent of description field is the things you have to do, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions and add your reasons for this request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @Leo, i have raised a feature request. I believe the reason is justified and makes sense. Let me know if you have different thoughts.