# Title of pullrequest same as Branchname

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

For pull requests in AzureDevops, im using ALWAYS the branch name as Pull reqeust title.

How can i set the branch name as default value for title?
I don't wanna type it again always :-)
I've checked the pull request templates, but am not able to make it for the title

[image]

Comment: I am afraid you couldn't custom `Title` field with pull request templates.MS does not provide a custom field other than the `description`.This thread has mentioned same issue:[Pull Request Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122535/add-field-in-pull-request-template-for-git-in-azure-devops)

Comment: Are you helped with my alternative solution here below? Please let me know or accept the answer as solution

Comment: Hi @promicro, nice idea, but I think with TamperMonkey it's only working for one device / one browser? 
Am searching for a solution, which works for multiple users in azure devops

Comment: True @R.Maier I’ll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I can think of is the use of [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/), there are lot of custom scripts around. This solution has the disadvantage that tampermonkey has to be installed in each browser individually.

I [searched](https://www.tampermonkey.net/scripts.php?ext=dhdg) several sources but couldn't find the exact thing, but I think if you know Javascript you can get inspired quickly by stuff like this:

- https://gist.github.com/2xAA/e7e91dfe2fb48fb5bdcb5403c3ddce43
- https://gist.github.com/robie2011/f1d5735855d5809d88b1b987e0fd2cec